# CSS Buttons into two columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a multiple choice quiz with between four and eight buttons. The problem I'm running into is getting them to go into two columns. I've tried using "columns: 2", but they turn out uneven, and I've tried changing the width of the list in order to force them but that hasn't worked for me either.

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sethkillian2/2t63v2nz/3/

```
<div id="central-area" class="central-area">

    <div class="main multiple-choice">
         <div class="question-row row column">
            <div class="question-text">
            vivre
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="hint row column">
            <span class="hint-text">Select the correct <strong>French</strong> for the <strong>English</strong> above:</span>
        </div>
        <ol class="choices clearfix ">
            <li class="shiny-box choice clearfix" data-choice-id="0">
                <span class="val ">to return</span>
                <span class="marking-icon"></span>
            </li>
            <li class="shiny-box choice clearfix" data-choice-id="1">
                <span class="val ">to wear</span>
                <span class="marking-icon"></span>
            </li>
            <li class="shiny-box choice clearfix" data-choice-id="2">
                <span class="val ">to sustain</span>
                <span class="marking-icon"></span>
            </li>
            <li class="shiny-box choice clearfix" data-choice-id="3">
                <span class="val ">to live</span>
                <span class="marking-icon"></span>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>  

</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.multiple-choice .hint {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 white;
    color: #aaa;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", "Kai", "KaiTi", Sans-Serif;
    padding: 11.42857px;
    font-size: 17.6px;
}

.multiple-choice .hint .hint-text {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden
}

.multiple-choice ol {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;=
}

.multiple-choice li {
    width: 260px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 8px 17px 8px 43px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.multiple-choice li:hover {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
}

.shiny-box {
    color: #6D6E70;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    border: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
    color: #3E3E3E;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", "Times", "Kai", "KaiTi", Serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 41px;
    transition: background-color 0.1s linear, opacity 0.1s linear, border-color 0.1s linear
}
```

And here's a picture of what I'd like vs what I have.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cKBw.jpg)

Comment: Is [THIS](https://jsfiddle.net/bonez0607/0vtjetzf/1/) what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes! Absolutely.

Comment: great I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `display:inline-block` to your `.choice` rule. This answer doesn't take advantage of Bootstrap however. I'll try and update the answer tonight to reflect using the [Bootstrap Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/).

```
.choice{ /*NEW*/
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
.choice{ /*NEW*/
  display: inline-block;
}

.central-area {
    width: 535px;
    margin: 16px auto 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 300;
}

.multiple-choice .question-row .question-text {
    display: inline;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    color: #3E3E3E;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Times New Roman","Times","Kai","KaiTi",Serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 360px;
}

.multiple-choice .hint {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 white;
    color: #aaa;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", "Kai", "KaiTi", Sans-Serif;
    padding: 11.42857px;
    font-size: 17.6px;
}

.multiple-choice .hint .hint-text {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden
}

.multiple-choice ol {
 display: block;
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;=
}

.multiple-choice li {
 width: 260px;
 margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 8px 17px 8px 43px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.multiple-choice li:hover {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
}

.shiny-box {
    color: #6D6E70;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    border: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
    color: #3E3E3E;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", "Times", "Kai", "KaiTi", Serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 41px;
    transition: background-color 0.1s linear, opacity 0.1s linear, border-color 0.1s linear
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="central-area" class="central-area">

 <div class="main multiple-choice">
         <div class="question-row row column">
          <div class="question-text">
         vivre
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="hint row column">
            <span class="hint-text">Select the correct <strong>French</strong> for the <strong>English</strong> above:</span>
        </div>
        <ol class="choices clearfix ">
      <li class="shiny-box choice clearfix" data-choice-id="0">
          <span class="val ">to return</span>
          <span class="marking-icon"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="shiny-box choice clearfix" data-choice-id="1">
          <span class="val ">to wear</span>
          <span class="marking-icon"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="shiny-box choice clearfix" data-choice-id="2">
          <span class="val ">to sustain</span>
          <span class="marking-icon"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="shiny-box choice clearfix" data-choice-id="3">
          <span class="val ">to live</span>
          <span class="marking-icon"></span>
      </li>
  </ol>
 </div> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple. I basically add `display: inline-block` to your `.shiny-box` class.

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2t63v2nz/5/) to your problem.